# how to determine the location of entries while creating a single file or directory from terminal

Tags: linux, centos, arch-linux, linux-kernel

I'm looking answers for very basic question in Linux environment.

Where to look for a entries related to that file or directory when we creating any file or directory from terminal ? 
for example:

```
 mkdir infinity
```

OR

```
 vi abc
 cat > abc
```

and
what will happens in the background when we creating right clicking on screen till creating any file or folder in desktop

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean with "entries". Are you referring to the file's metadata or the content? And where do you "right-click"?

Comment: `mkdir infinity` will create a folder called infinity in your current directory. To check your current directory use `pwd` command. `vi abc` will try to open a file called `abc` in your current directory. `cat abc` will look for `abc` in your current directory and print out it's contents into `stdout`. When you create files and folders with GUI it does the same `mkdir` or `touch` commands in the background. If by entries you mean you want to know more about a file use `file` command, example `file abc`.

Comment: i understand linux is a file based system. and it keeps a records and make somewhere entries regarding our activity whatever we do. so i'm looking for those entries details whenever we create, update, read, delete any file or folder where it keep the records related to those files and directory. i mean in this process what will happen in the background

Comment: basically i'm interested to see what will happen in background if any event trigger.

Comment: do you mean the audit system? Try reading [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Audit_framework) ...

Answer (score 1):

We should use [strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to trace system calls and signals

Try as

```
strace mkdir infinity
```

Comment: i will try this